# Nuget Solution-Level alternative

Tags: visual-studio-2017, nuget

I have read about Nuget Solution-Level package has been deprecated. Is there an alternative for that? or Which would be the best way to work with a multiple project solution that it is being shared between developers without breaking the references?

Comment: Hi Alan, any update for this issue? There is a [discussion](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1521) about bringing it back in github, you can check it. In some situation, if the projects in the solution need to have different nuget version of same package, the Solution-level nuget can't meet the needs well. And to work with a multiple project solution, have you tried to use packageReference format to manage nuget packages ? It could be a good choice. Any update please feel free to contact me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to have be deprecated in Nuget 3.0.

According to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/faqs/nuget-faq#working-with-packages): Maybe the option `Manage Nuget Packages for Solution` is what you want.

In VS2017, if you have a multiple-project solution, right-click the solution name in `Solution Explorer` and click `Manage Nuget Packages for Solution` to manage solution packages:

[image]

Visual Studio makes it easy to manage NuGet packages for multiple projects in a solution using this option.

**Update:**
There is a [discussion](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1521) about bringing them back.